# Discover information from a column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, which are df_First:

```
      df_First = pd.DataFrame({'Car Model': ['Fiesta 2010', 'Fiesta 2010', 'Cruze 2020', 'Fiesta 
                               2005'], 
                              'Car Plate End': [749, 749, 100, 200],
                              'Car Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Black'],
                              'Num Door': [2,2,4,4]})
      print(df_First)


      Car Model        Car Plate End    Car Color   Num Door
     Fiesta 2010          749             Red         2
     Fiesta 2010          749             Red         2
     Cruze 2020           100             Blue        4
     Fiesta 2005          200             Black       4
```

and df_Second:

```
        df_Second = pd.DataFrame({'Car Plate End': [749, 749, 749, 100, 749, 100, 200, 500], 
                                  'Cost_Max': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
                                  'Cost_Min': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})
       print(df_Second)

      Car Plate End   Cost_Max  Cost_Min
          749           10         1
          749           20         2
          749           30         3
          100           40         4
          749           50         5
          100           60         6
          200           70         7
          500           80         8
```

I would like to create a new dataframe (which was the same 
number of lines as the df_Second). It must contain the car model based on the end of the car plate.

The desired output is as follows:

```
      Car Plate End   Cost_Max  Cost_Min  Car Model
          749           10         1        Fiesta 2010
          749           20         2        Fiesta 2010
          749           30         3        Fiesta 2010
          100           40         4        Cruze 2020
          749           50         5        Fiesta 2010
          100           60         6        Cruze 2020
          200           70         7        Fiesta 2005    
          500           80         8        NaN
```

I tried to implement the following code:

```
       df_Total = pd.merge(df_Second, df_First, on=['Car Plate End'], how='outer')
```

However, my departure is not being as desired. The output is:

```
       Car Plate End    Cost_Max    Cost_Min    Car Model     Car Color  Num Door
            749            10          1        Fiesta 2010     Red      2.0
            749            10          1        Fiesta 2010     Red      2.0
            749            20          2        Fiesta 2010     Red      2.0
            749            20          2        Fiesta 2010     Red      2.0
            749            30          3        Fiesta 2010     Red      2.0
            749            30          3        Fiesta 2010     Red     2.0
            749            50          5        Fiesta 2010     Red     2.0
            749            50          5        Fiesta 2010     Red     2.0
            100            40          4        Cruze 2020      Blue    4.0
            100            60          6        Cruze 2020      Blue    4.0
            200            70          7        Fiesta 2005     Black   4.0
            500            80          8        NaN             NaN     NaN
```

I just needed to find out which model of car the df_Second refers to. I don't need the other columns. I would also like df_Total to have the same number of lines as df_Second.
Thank you so much for your help and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue to address is that your first dataframe contains duplicated relationships that need to be dropped. There are several ways to achieve the result, including `merge`, `join`, `map`. Here is the `join` approach,

```
map_unique = df_First.groupby('Car Plate End')['Car Model'].first()

df_Second.join(map_unique, on='Car Plate End')
```

Comment: @JaneBorges Try working with merge, after `drop_duplicates` on the first one and do a  *left* merge